# How to increase Akka-http websockets performance

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I need to make websocket server application to hold connections and resend messages (about 100k connections on single machine). To understand if scala/akka-http is a good choose for this I made a test.
Server-side code:

```
object Server2 {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       implicit val system = ActorSystem()
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

       def echoFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
           Flow[Message].mapConcat {
               case tm: TextMessage => 
                   TextMessage(Source.single("test ") ++ tm.textStream) :: Nil
           }

       val websocketRoute =
           path("chat") {
               handleWebSocketMessages(echoFlow)
           }

       val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(websocketRoute, "127.0.0.1", 8080)

       // the rest of the sample code will go here
       println("Started server at 127.0.0.1:8080, press enter to kill server")
       StdIn.readLine()
       system.terminate()
    }
}
```

Server just sends message back to the client. Client I wrote on nodejs.

I made 10k connections to the server and each connection sends message once in 10sec. (message it's current timestamp). Test showed that server uses 70% CPU and 1.5GB ram. On 18k connections, server stops to connect new clients.

I wrote another server, this time on nodejs + ws. On same machine it showed much better performance 100k connections with 70% CPU usage.
I'm new in scala and my question is what I do wrong? 
Or scala + akka-http are not suitable for such kind of tasks, I mean websockets.

I run server on my machine (intel i5-7500 3.4Ghz. 16GB ram. OS Windows 10 Pro. Java SE 64-bit 1.8.0_171).

Answer (score 3):

Check the Akka Http documentation https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html.

Check if it works declaring your source like that:

```
def echoFlow0: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
  Flow[Message].collect {
    case tm: TextMessage.Strict =>
      TextMessage.Strict("Test " + tm.text)
  }
```